# Does this variation on "return last numeric value in column" formula have any known fail conditions that anyone can see?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The parameters are:

1. The column may contain either negative or positive numbers (including the decimals forms of proper fractions), blank cells, text or errors (like `#DIV/0!`), and will have data added to it over time.
2. It uses `LOOKUP` in its vector form.

The formula (with Column A as the column in question) is:

`=LOOKUP(1,-1/A:A^2,A:A)`

The thinking is

1. First make sure any negative numbers are positive by squaring them using `A:A^2`
2. Make all the numbers negative by using `-1/<resulting number from 1.>`.
3. Then, when `LOOKUP` goes looking for the value 1, it will exploit the behaviour of `LOOKUP` to return the last number in column for a value that it can't find that is greater than any of the numbers in the resulting array.

I think it works in all circumstances, but can anyone see something that breaks it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work if the last number is zero, that will generate a #DIV/0! error which LOOKUP will ignore

Why not

`=LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,A:A)`

Comment: It makes 0.5 into -4, though. That's the point of `-1/<resulting number from 1.>.`

Comment: No, I got that wrong, apologies Endlessloop......but what if the last number is zero, that will convert to an error so the LOOKUP will ignore it, do you want to show zeroes?

Comment: BINGO! D'oh + facepalm. You found an obvious fail condition. I wanted to avoid the 9.99999999999999E+307 trick, but I might not be able to. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine it will be less efficient than using 9.9999999999....but how about `=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(A:A),A:A)`?

Comment: No, there are no large numbers - 1/ISNUMBER(A:A) generates an array entirely consisting of 1s (when the value is a number) or #DIV/0! errors (when the value is not a number)

Comment: Yes, I just realised -- I think you've cracked it -- thanks again! Do you want to modify your answer to include that solution?